# Android: Uploading number of images causing Heap size to grow big - how to solve that?

Tags: android

I'm writing app where user can take bunch of pictures (up to 20) and upload to server. Images need to be uploaded all together.

Here is my logic:

1. Take each picture, display thumb on a screen and resize picture on SD to 800x600 with 90 quality
2. Create object, populate properties (images) as Base64 string
3. Serialize object using GSON
4. Upload string

While testing I was getting errors "Out of Memory" when I was processing images. I thought and this is where all StackOverflow complains is - that it's some bug with BitmapFactory. Yes, error mostly shows up while resizing image but it is NOT related to this operation.

While I take pictures and process them (resize, etc) - heap size stays below 7-8mb. It's just 2-3Mb more than my usual app state.

When I submit those images to server and GSON + Base64 encoder comes into play - than it "explodes" and I get this:

[image]

Well - as you see - after process completed Allocated memory get's down as expected but Heap Size stays. Now, when I take more pictures or do something with app - I start to get those out of memory errors.

Here is my code to upload JSON. Any suggestions on improving it or handling something like that? Maybe I can stream JSON into file and do http from file or something?

```
while (!c.isAfterLast())
        {
            String data = c.getString(colObjectData);
            TrailerInspection trailerInspection = MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson().fromJson(data, TrailerInspection.class);

            //Load image data
            for (TrailerUnitInspection trailerUnitInspection : trailerInspection.UnitInspections)
            {
                for (FileContainer fileContainer : trailerUnitInspection.Images)
                {
                    fileContainer.dataFromFile(mContext);
                }
            }

            data = MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson().toJson(trailerInspection);

            MyHttpResponse response = processPOST("/trips/" + c.getString(colTripId) + "/trailerinspection", data);

            if (response.Code ==  HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                processed.add(c.getString(colGId));
            }

            c.moveToNext();
        }
        c.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating and keeping whole string, which is prepared to sending, in internal memory.

```
String data = MyGsonWrapper.getMyGson().toJson(trailerInspection);
```

This string may be very large. You should stream your data in chunks to server.
I haven't used gson yet, but in docs I found something like [JsonWriter](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/stream/JsonWriter.html). Take a look at this class.

UPDATE:

```
ContentProducer cp = new ContentProducer() {
    public void writeTo(OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outstream, "UTF-8"));
        // write code here
        writer.flush();
    }
};
HttpEntity entity = new EntityTemplate(cp);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://server.address");
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: I will look at JsonWriter. But how do I pass that stream into HttpClient? It takes StringEntity..

Comment: There is example: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html#Request_Response_entity_streaming

Comment: Seems like PostMethod used in example already removed from Android. Do I understand correctly that my goal is to Stream object to the file(internal or SD) and than do http post streaming directly from SD? If I create in-memory stream from GSON memory still going to be taxed?

Comment: Thanks again. Took me a while to figure "//write code here" :) Since my object is quite complex and I had to manually do it property by property with JsonWriter. But now all is well. Heap size goes up by 3-4mb with worst case scenarios. Phew..